# Is it possible for me to rotate symbols and operations?

Tags: support, mathjax

I wanted to rotate $\Box$ $45^\circ$ clockwise to make a diamond. At the time, I did not know there was a diamond command $\diamond$ and $\Diamond$ and $\diamondsuit$ and even things like $\not\diamondsuit$. But I then wondered to myself, is there a command to *rotate* symbols? For instance, say I had the letter $\Psi$. I can rotate this, only $180^\circ$ but not with some fancy rotating command. Simply, I use **\pitchfork** and this generates $\pitchfork$. A bit like a flip. I can also flip curved lines. For instance, take the curve $\frown$. I can flip it $180^\circ$ but with an entirely seperate command, **\smile** to generate $\smile$.

The examples that I mentioned however, are only *certain* examples where I can flip them. For example, I can flip arrows. $\downarrow$ $\leftarrow$ $\uparrow$ $\rightarrow$ $\wedge$ $>$ $\lor$ $<$, but none of these uses a rotating command; only directions. But say I want to flip the curve $\smile$ only $90^\circ$. Then how would I do that? I can write the command, **\between** but this generates $\between$ which is both curves flipped $90^\circ$, not one. I would simply have to use brackets $()$. And if I wanted to rotate a symbol like $\gtrless$ then what command do I use now? I would have to use two commands to generate $\land\lor$ and $\lor\land$ but I won't be able to flip $\gtrless$ sideways.

Essentially, I am asking if there is some kind of rotating command, and if not, is it ok to feature some kind of command like that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible using the [HTML extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/html.html)

```
$$\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(45deg)}{\Box}$$
```

$$\require{HTML}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(45deg)}{\Box}$$

Comment: @user477343 I knew this could be accomplished in $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ using `\rotatebox` so that was the first thing I looked for in the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). Since that wasn't there, my next thought was that this could be done with CSS. When I looked through the MathJax extensions, I found the HTML extension and all that was left to do is see if I could use it on StackExchange.

Comment: Note that CSS transforms don't affect the bounding box of the content, so if you have a short width character, its bounding box will not become a tall this character.  E.g., $\bbox[red]{\style{display:inline-block; transform:rotate(90deg)}{\longrightarrow}}\Rule{0px}{1em}{.25em}$.  This has implications when the rotated character is used between two others.

Comment: It also means that in HTML-CSS output, which is clipped to the bounding box, part of the character might be clipped: $\bbox[red]{\style{display:inline-block; transform:rotate(90deg)}{\longrightarrow}}$ (I added spacing above to prevent that, though it only affects HTML-CSS output, not CommonHTML output).

Comment: This technique only works for HTML-CSS, CommonHTML, and NativeMML output (in particular, not for SVG output), so some users (those who have selected SVG output) will not see what you expect them to.

Comment: Note that this only affects the *visual* representation, so users with assistive technology (like screen readers) will get the wrong output.  E.g., in the arrow example above, they will be told it is a right arrow, not a down arrow.  So while such hacks are possible, they are not recommended if you are interested in supporting all your readers.

Comment: Finally, note that the `HTML` extension is loaded automatically when needed, so there is no need for the explicit `\require{HTML}`.

Comment: @mr_e_man It's a CSS feature, not MathJax. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp (either a scale or a matrix will work). But you should seek a solution that doesn't require CSS for the reasons Davide has outlined.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that "scale" could have two parameters. $F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(-1,1)}{F}$

Comment: This is gonna generate lot of crazy/ interesting symbols (like the comment by @mr_e_man) :)