# Rendering MathJaX: cropped formulas

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, display-math-mode

In my recent Question [Limit without de l'Hôpital: $\lim _{x\to 0\color{red}{\boldsymbol -}}\left(1+x^3\right)^{\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^4-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797893/limit-without-de-lh%c3%b4pital-lim-x-to-0-colorred-boldsymbol-left1x3) there is a problem of visualization. I have seen that some formulas are cropped? What is the cause?

Do you seen my same problem of visualization (see the $x^3$)?

[image]

**EDIT:** After the comment of the user @Paramanand Singh. The image is increasing of the 200%.

[image]

Comment: It looks fine in my setup (Firefox on Android). Try to zoom the page and see finer details to confirm if you have a problem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you $x\to+\infty$ for your feddback...I use Chrome on OS W8.1 64 bit.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have edit...but there is the same problem.

Comment: Ok there is some issue at your end as the zoomed image shows. But its hard to tell why. Maybe some mathjax experts can share their feedback.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I am a modest user of TeX.SE. Generally on TeX.SE. questions on MathJaX are off-topic. I honestly wouldn't know who to ask. Thank you very much.

Comment: The cropping is probably because the parentheses height is not as much as the height required. But somehow this is working fine at my end even with the height mismatch.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If you could give me an answer on how to better write a formula without this cropping, I would be grateful.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The particular equation the OP asked about is also cropped on my $1280$ x $1024$ display. Note I'm using Microsoft Edge, version $84.0.522.61$, on $64$-bit Windows $10$. I've also seen this bottom cropping issue happen with some of my other equations, although this only seemed to start at least several months after I first joined here. [Questions with mathjax don't fit in the box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283191/562482) from $4$ years ago describes a problem with bottom text being cut off. Although it has supposedly been fixed, this current issue may be related.

Comment: @JohnOmielan more recent is [this bug](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28889/80734) i filed due to the site redesign in 2018. I [also have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x78pl.png) this problem on my mac, but its more often a problem for the top of tall formulae, and I have been too lazy to bring it up. In addition, I will note that the Mathjax Zoom feature, which [was also broken](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28939/80734) by the site redesign also does not work for me, except for inline math (just as before!)

Comment: Try switching the renderer using the MathJax contextual menu (on any typeset math).  Which renderer are you currently using?

Comment: @DavideCervone Can you explain better your question? I have not understood.

Comment: MathJax has several different output formats.  The older HTML-CSS (which is the default on StackOverflow) does use clip regions and may be the source of the problem you are seeing.  The CommonHTML format should not have that problem.  The SVG format might also show clipping, since the SVG element itself acts as a clipping region.  (unless specially instructed not to).  So if you change to CommonHTML you might have better results.  My question was which renderer are you using, and you can find the out using the Mathjax contextual menu (Math Settings -> Math Render) when you change the renderer.

Comment: I've seen them get cropped at the top. I don't recall having seen it at the bottom like this.

Comment: This may be a problem with the PPI/DPI of the device. Try to use 
 \large{}  or \Large{} or \Huge to make your texts look $$\Huge{BIGGER}$$

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi A bit of $\LaTeX$ I know it :-) Thank you for the suggestion. I'm very glad of your help.

Comment: @DavideCervone Can you swith, please, your comment, as an answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try switching the renderer using the MathJax contextual menu (on any typeset math).  MathJax has several different output formats. The older HTML-CSS (which is the default on StackOverflow) does use clip regions and may be the source of the problem you are seeing. The CommonHTML format should not have that problem. The SVG format might also show clipping, since the SVG element itself acts as a clipping region (unless specially instructed not to). So if you change to CommonHTML you might have better results. Use the Mathjax contextual menu (Math Settings -> Math Render) to change the renderer.

[image]

Comment: Please, can you put some screenshots...You're too technical and I should interpret... It's lucky that I know any English language.

Comment: @Sebastiano, OK, there is an image of the menus you need to use.  Right-Click on any typeset math to get it.

Comment: @DavideCervone I note "Right-Click" is absent from your answer, perhaps "Try switching the renderer using the MathJax contextual menu (**Right-Click** on any typeset math). " would be good

Comment: @DavideCervone Ah, I thinked other :-(...I know the procedure, I'm sorry. But it is ok: very good...Perfect!

Comment: @Sebastiano To you, & anybody else, considering changing to "Common HTML", note I did that. Although it fixed the bottom being cut off, I switched back as it caused a more serious (at least to me) problem of longer MathJax display equations being cut off on the right side, as I describe in my main SE Meta post of [Longer MathJax display equations are partially cut off on the right side when using the "Common HTML" math renderer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353757/562482). As I stated in this other post, I didn't try any other renderer, so it may be one of them works better in all cases.

Comment: Meantime thank you very much for your contribute and cooperation. I will take in consideration to change "Common HTML". All the best and excuse me for my poor English. I'm not native speaker.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code in question `(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)`:
$$(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)$$
For some reason, mathematics renders *perfectly* on math.meta for me, but not on the main site. (If only it was the other way round...) Is it the same for you?  In any case, a sub-question from the comments:

> how to better write a formula without this cropping

There is a way to force a formula to have more vertical space, by placing `\Rule{A px}{B em}{C em}` at the end. Then, the cropped part of the image will just be white-space, which I would say is more acceptable. Here, `A` is the horizontal thickness, `B` is the length of the rule above the baseline, and `C` is the length below the baseline.

For instance `(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)\Rule{20 px}{3 em}{0 em}\Rule{20 px}{0 em}{5 em}`:
$$(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)\Rule{20 px}{3 em}{0 em}\Rule{20 px}{0 em}{5 em}$$
If you put `0` for the first input, then the rule takes no horizontal space but the bounding box is increased, e.g.
$$\bbox[green]{(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)\Rule{0 px}{3 em}{3 em}} \qquad \text{V.S.} \qquad \bbox[green]{(1+x^3)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac1{x^3}}\right)}$$
Learned from the comments of Davide to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27799/80734).

Comment: Thankkkkk you very much. I have accepted the first answer...but your is also fine.