# How to rotate text by 180° and or mirror it in Math.SE?

Tags: support, mathjax, typesetting

I'd like to rotate and mirror text left-right in Math.SE, as plain text or inside formulae.  What I tried is from a [TeX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93797/how-to-rotate-text-inline) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161788/how-to-have-upside-down-text-in-body)
like:

```
$\require{rotating}$
$\require{graphicx}$
$\rotatebox{180}{Text}$
```

but all I get is

$\require{rotating}$
$\require{graphicx}$
$\rotatebox{180}{Text}$

If possible, I'd prefer a solution that does not use special charactes like $\forall$ (`$\forall$`) for an unside-down $A$.

Combinations of rotations of 180° and mirror about vertical axis will do for me.

Comment: It has some shortcomings, but take a look as [this previous Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/is-it-possible-for-me-to-rotate-symbols-and-operations) to see if it gives a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially from the post linked by hardmath,
[Is it possible for me to rotate symbols and operations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/is-it-possible-for-me-to-rotate-symbols-and-operations)

Horizontal mirror:
`F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(-1,1)}{F}` gives
$$F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(-1,1)}{F}$$
Vertical mirror:`F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(1,-1)}{F}` gives
$$F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(1,-1)}{F}$$
Rotation by 180º:`F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{F}` gives
$$F\mapsto\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{F}$$
(or alternatively `scale(-1,-1)`)