# Left pointing vector accent

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I'd like to typeset $\vec{\square}$ but with the arrow pointing left, where $\square$ stands for an arbitrary letter from the Latin alphabet. I've tried to implement the solution described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15012/21685), however it uses the `\reflectbox` command, which [MathJax doesn't support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html#r). How can a left pointing vector accent be implemented in MathJax?

Comment: Related from earlier this year, [How to rotate text by 180 and/or mirror it in Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-rotate-text-by-180-and-or-mirror-it-in-math-se).  But the idea below seems much less work.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks! I posted an alternative answer below based on the post you linked to.

Comment: Voting to migrate this to [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{\mathbf{#1}}}$
In general, you can put one thing on top of another using `\stackrel{topthing}{bottomthing}`.  It's natural to use `\leftarrow` as the top thing, but it will look too large unless you modify it:  `\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\mathbf{v}}` gives $\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\mathbf{v}}$. You can make a symbol a lot smaller with `\tiny`: `\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{\mathbf{v}}` gives $\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{\mathbf{v}}$ which has an arrow about the same size as the one produced by `\vec{\mathbf{v}}`: $\vec{\mathbf{v}}$ although a bit less bold.  I don't know a heavier left arrow symbol.

To avoid typing out the full command every time, you can do `\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{\mathbf{#1}}}` at the top of your answer. Then `\cev{u}` will produce $\cev{u}$

Comment: Alas, I think the scaling depends on the MathJax renderer. Here's what I see using the default "HTML-CSS" renderer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUOCr.png And here's what I (and, I suspect, you) see if I switch to the "Common HTML" renderer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFce.png (Screenshots taken on Firefox 104.0.2 / macOS 12.5.1; behavior on Chrome 105.0.5195.125 and Safari 15.6.1 is pretty much the same.) [Evan Aad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35138)'s answer works great for me on both renderers, though.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an alternative solution to [Matthew's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35133/37058), based on [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34790/37058), which I was made aware of thanks to [hardmath's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35132/left-pointing-vector-accent?noredirect=1#comment165340_35132).

`\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1)}{\vec{\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1)}{#1}}}}`
$\newcommand{\cev}[1]{\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1)}{\vec{\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1)}{#1}}}}$

Using this command, `\cev{y}` produces $\cev{y}$. For comparison, `\vec{y}` produces $\vec{y}$, and Matthew's code produces $\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{y}$.

One advantage of my code over Matthew's is that with my code the arrow stretches automatically when more than one letter is involved. Thus, `\cev{xy}` produces $\cev{xy}$, whereas Matthew's code produces $\stackrel{\tiny\leftarrow}{xy}$. For comparison, `\vec{xy}` produces $\vec{xy}$.

Answer (score 4):

A standard command exists for this: `\overleftarrow{PQ}` for $\overleftarrow{PQ}$.

<s>In fact, `\vec` is defined to be a shorthand for `\overrightarrow`.</s>

Comment: I don't think your second sentence can be correct - `\vec{v}` gives $\vec{v}$ which has a very different size arrow to `\overrightarrow{v}` which makes $\overrightarrow{v}$

Comment: @MatthewTowers My fault. `\vec` is a (simple) math accent while `\overrightarrow` is an extensible accent.